# String substitution does not work when pattern contains "["

Tags: regex, linux, shell, ash

I have the following string

```
str="aaa.bbb.1.ccc.[mmm]."
```

If I make substitution with the following command, then it works

```
# echo ${str/ccc.\[mmm\]./}
aaa.bbb.1.
```

Now I want to put the pattern into a variable, then the substitution command will not work

```
# var="ccc.\[mmm\]."
# echo ${str/$var/}
aaa.bbb.1.ccc.[mmm].

# var="ccc.[mmm]."
# echo ${str/$var/}
aaa.bbb.1.ccc.[mmm].
```

How I can make the substitution work with the pattern defined in a variable?

Comment: Not sure hence the comment, but maybe you need to escape it twice?

Comment: `var="ccc.\[mmm\]."` works for me in BASH

Comment: if you mean ` var="ccc.\\[mmm\\]."` , this also did not work

Comment: What does `awk` have to do with this? Are you actually running this in `ash`? The escaped version works for me in bash and ksh and the non-escaped works in zsh.

Comment: This is a case when `eval` can come handy: does `eval echo ${str/$var/}` work to you? Also, it does work to me in Bash 4.2, like @anubhava

Comment: Double escape for once interpolated once by shell it ends up escaped in the cariable call: `var="ccc.\\\[mmm\\\]."` (3 \, to get an escaped backslash and an escaped bracket, with a space it would give: `\\ \[` => `\ [` after var is set.) Another (simplest) way is to stop interpolation when assigning the var by using single quotes.

Comment: Forgot to say I suspect you're not using bash as the others already point ou, so speaking on the behavior you get more than something really sure.

Comment: I got `Bad substitution` even if I try it without the variable. Which version of `ash` are you using?

Comment: Your question is tagged `ash`.

`ash` does not support the `${var/$source/$replacement}` parameter expansion at all. What shell are you *really* using?

Answer (score 0):

Put the expression in double quotes:

```
echo "${str/$var/}"
```

Works for me on busybox:

```
# str="aaa.bbb.1.ccc.[mmm]."
# echo ${str/ccc.\[mmm\]./}
aaa.bbb.1.
# var="ccc.\[mmm\]."
# echo ${str/$var/}
aaa.bbb.1.ccc.[mmm].
# echo "${str/$var/}"
aaa.bbb.1.
# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May  9 05:22 /bin/sh -> busybox
#
```